# tree structure using append child in javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried to create  tree structure using javascript append child .
I have created a add button.On clicking add button a root node is created.On clicking root, parent node is created.                   **But on clicking parent, Both parent node and child node is created**. I need to create only child node while clicking parent. How to proceed?

```js
  function add_div(){
  var div1 = document.createElement('ul');
  document.body.appendChild(div1);
  div1.className = 'ui-modal';
  div1.id = 'test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.ui-modal > .msg1').length;

  div1.innerHTML = '<li class="msg1" onclick="add_div2(this);">root</li>';
}

function add_div2(elem){
     var div2 = document.createElement('ul');
     elem.appendChild(div2);
      div2.className = 'sub-div';
      div2.id = 'sub_test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.sub-div > .msg2').length;
      div2.innerHTML = '<li class="msg2" onclick="add_div3(this);">parent</li>';
}


function add_div3(elem){
     var div3 = document.createElement('ul');
     elem.appendChild(div3);
      div3.className = 'inner-sub-div';
      div3.id = 'inner_sub_test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.inner-sub-div > .msg3').length;
      div3.innerHTML = '<li class="msg3" >child</li>';
}
```

```css
 .ui-modal{
     width: 100px;
     border: 1px solid red;
      margin-left:0;
}
    .sub-div{
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 150px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
}
    .inner-sub-div{
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 150px;
        margin-left: 250px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="add_div();">
</div>
```

I have used ul and li in script to create append child. How to create a child node on clicking parent node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  `event.stopPropagation();` in onclick function

```js
  function add_div(){
  var div1 = document.createElement('ul');
  document.body.appendChild(div1);
  div1.className = 'ui-modal';
  div1.id = 'test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.ui-modal > .msg1').length;

  div1.innerHTML = '<li class="msg1" onclick="event.stopPropagation();add_div2(this);">root</li>';
}

function add_div2(elem){
     var div2 = document.createElement('ul');
     elem.appendChild(div2);
      div2.className = 'sub-div';
      div2.id = 'sub_test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.sub-div > .msg2').length;
      div2.innerHTML = '<li class="msg2" onclick="event.stopPropagation();add_div3(this);">parent</li>';
}


function add_div3(elem){
     var div3 = document.createElement('ul');
     elem.appendChild(div3);
      div3.className = 'inner-sub-div';
      div3.id = 'inner_sub_test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.inner-sub-div > .msg3').length;
      div3.innerHTML = '<li class="msg3" >child</li>';
}
```

```css
 .ui-modal{
     width: 100px;
     border: 1px solid red;
      margin-left:0;
}
    .sub-div{
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 150px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
}
    .inner-sub-div{
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 150px;
        margin-left: 250px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="add_div();">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.Working fine.This what We expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use      `event.stopPropagation();` on click of parent div

```js
function add_div(){
  var div1 = document.createElement('ul');
  document.body.appendChild(div1);
  div1.className = 'ui-modal';
  div1.id = 'test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.ui-modal > .msg1').length;

  div1.innerHTML = '<li class="msg1" onclick="add_div2(event,this);">root</li>';
}

function add_div2(event,elem){
  
     var div2 = document.createElement('ul');
     elem.appendChild(div2);
      div2.className = 'sub-div';
      div2.id = 'sub_test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.sub-div > .msg2').length;
      div2.innerHTML = '<li class="msg2" onclick="add_div3(event,this);">parent</li>';
}


function add_div3(event,elem){
     var div3 = document.createElement('ul');
     event.stopPropagation();
     elem.appendChild(div3);
      div3.className = 'inner-sub-div';
      div3.id = 'inner_sub_test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.inner-sub-div > .msg3').length;
      console.log()
      div3.innerHTML = '<li class="msg3" >child</li>';
}
```

```css
 .ui-modal{
     width: 100px;
     border: 1px solid red;
      margin-left:0;
}
    .sub-div{
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 150px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
}
    .inner-sub-div{
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 150px;
        margin-left: 250px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="add_div();">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.worked fine.How to delete the child and parent node?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of the event bubbling. 
Your click on `child` is getting propagated to `parent` ul as well thus clicking twice effect is created.

Stop this propagation using "`stopPropagation()`", for this you need event object, you can pass that in your functions.

Read more about events here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events
and about event bubbling, scroll down to the "Event bubbling and capture" section on that page.

```js
function add_div(){
  var div1 = document.createElement('ul');
  document.body.appendChild(div1);
  div1.className = 'ui-modal';
  div1.id = 'test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.ui-modal > .msg1').length;

  div1.innerHTML = '<li class="msg1" onclick="add_div2(event, this);">root</li>';
}

function add_div2(event, elem){
    event.stopPropagation();
     var div2 = document.createElement('ul');
     elem.appendChild(div2);
      div2.className = 'sub-div';
      div2.id = 'sub_test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.sub-div > .msg2').length;
      div2.innerHTML = '<li class="msg2" onclick="add_div3(event, this);">parent</li>';
}


function add_div3(event,elem){
event.stopPropagation();
     var div3 = document.createElement('ul');
     elem.appendChild(div3);
      div3.className = 'inner-sub-div';
      div3.id = 'inner_sub_test-' + document.querySelectorAll('.inner-sub-div > .msg3').length;
      div3.innerHTML = '<li class="msg3" >child</li>';
}
```

```css
.ui-modal{
     width: 100px;
     border: 1px solid red;
      margin-left:0;
}
    .sub-div{
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 150px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
}
    .inner-sub-div{
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 150px;
        margin-left: 250px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="add_div();">
</div>
```